# How to make scroll automatically down?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `div` which have style `overflow-y`

But when I open the page, I need the div already scrolled down

I have about 100 divs in a page, so it would be good if the solution would be simple and optimized.

Thank you very much for your time!

[image]

Comment: You have to be more specific. Clear your question by add some codes. If you have a divs. You should have the `html` and `css`. Just put those codes here.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Javascript:**

```
var divobj = document.getElementById("div_id");
divobj.scrollTop = divobj.scrollHeight;
```

**Using Jquery:**

```
$("#div_id").scrollTop($("#div_id")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var div = document.getElementById('yourDiv');
 div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tr this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```